# Inverter : drive with high impedance. Results on the output

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, inverter, logic-gates, high-impedance

I have to compile a 9-valued logic table for a circuit.
I would like to know what happen to the output of an inverter and of a pass-transistor-gate if driven in high impedance.

Specifically in this circuit :
a1=Z 
a2=1 (or HIGH)

Why y=WEAK?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what software this is:

Assume that the gates are all ideal. When a1=Z, all three of its attached gates are floating. However, assuming a perfect inverter attached to a1, then one of the FETs in the pass gate will always be conducting. As such, regardless of what voltage a1 floats to, there will be a path for current from Vdd, through R, through the pass gate, to Y. If R has a high resistance, it will be considered a "weak pullup".

In practice, don't do this. Never leave inputs floating, especially FETs.